# anychart line - xScale limited input data + offset

Tags: input, limit, anychart

Maximum data on screen is 31 point + offset. In my input i have 50 points.
How set more?

Image
[image]

**Example**
*JavaScript code and more detail here*
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

axisX is days, problem here

```
//array
arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
}
//object x y
const data = []

const time = new Date().getTime();
const oneDay = 1000*60*60*24

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    const day = new Date( time + ( oneDay * (i+1) ) );   
    const currentDate = day.getDate()

    data.push( { 
        x: 'day: ' + currentDate,
        y: arr[i]
    } );
}

// create line chart
chart = anychart.line();
// set chart padding
chart.padding([5, 5, 5, 5]);
// turn on chart animation
chart.animation(false);
// turn on the crosshair
chart.crosshair(false);
// set chart title text settings
const name = 'Name'
chart.title(name);
// set y axis title
chart.yAxis().title('Price');
chart.xScale()
var series;
series = chart.line(data);
series.name('series name');
series.labels().enabled(true).anchor('right-bottom').padding(2);
series.labels().enabled(true).anchor('left-bottom').padding(2);
series.markers(true);
// turn the legend on
chart.legend().enabled(true).fontSize(11).padding([0, 0, 10, 0]);
chart.container('chartContainer');
chart.draw();
```

Comment: Can you provide the full chart configuration code and the exact data? The code you provided doesn't match the result on the screenshot. The code with the linear array in the data provides the following result - https://playground.anychart.com/gdb88sP6

Comment: i found problem, if i send data to AxisX days, on image days, just copy past

Comment: ```arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
}

const data = []

const time = new Date().getTime();
const oneDay = 1000*60*60*24

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    const day = new Date( time + ( oneDay * (i+1) ) );   
    const currentDate = day.getDate()

    data.push( { 
        x: 'day: ' + currentDate,
        y: arr[i]
    } );
}```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are using a Cartesian chart which default xScale is Ordinal. The Ordinal scale works with categories, it assumes that all categories are unique. But your data set includes doubling categories, like `day: 19`, `day: 20`, etc. So, the next point with the same category name overrides the previous one.
In your case, you should use dateTime scale and real dateTime X coordinates (string date, timestamp in ms, Date class object). For details, check [the article](https://docs.anychart.com/Axes_and_Grids/Scales#date_time).